# \input can't find file (nested directory structure)

Tags: input

I have the following directory structure in my project:

```
main.tex
LaTeX
    mypackage.sty
content
  chapter2.tex
    figures
      LaTeX
         figure.tex
```

In `main.tex` I input `content/chapter2.tex`. I also use the package defined in `mypackage.sty` which contains all of my setup code (such as using packages etc.).

`figure.tex` contains some tikz code. I'd like to input it into `content/chapter2.tex`. However when I use `\input{./figures/LaTeX/figure}` it tells me it can't find the file even though it exists.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It should be `\input{content/figures/LaTeX/figure)`, the path is relative to the main file. Use the import package to change this.

Comment: See the [import](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import) package to establish input relative to a directory.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer (+1) can you edit your comment?

Comment: Assuming you are compiling main.tex, which is in a directory above `content`, then these should work: `\input{./content/chapter2.tex}` and `\input{./content/figures/LaTeX/figure}`

Answer (score 5):

It should be `\input{content/figures/LaTeX/figure)`, the path is relative to the main file. Use the import package to change this. (I'm certain that there is a duplicate to this question somewhere).